# RxJS - stop requests with same parameters being made twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's say I have the following endpoint: /students/id.

I want to block a request with the same id being made multiple times (example: /students/1), but allow another request if the id is different.

I haven't been able to find a solution, operators like exhaustMap are not helping me/don't know how to use them for this case. I have also read about shareReplay but I don't know how to use it to take into account the parameters.

**Edit**

I'm actually using NGRX to accomplish my task. The issue is that I have several "student" components on one page that may make a requests to the same endpoint (/students/1) but display the same data in a different way. I can't check if the data is available with "withLatestFrom" because the requests are being dispatched one after another so there isn't enough time for the first requests to finish.
I also can't use exhaustMap because I don't want to block every requests to /students/id (2 components will need the data from /students/1 and another from /students/2)

```
getStudentEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(getStudent),
    exhaustMap((payload) => this.studentsService.get({id: payload.id})
      .pipe(
        map(student=> ({ type: '[Students API] Student Loaded Success', payload: student})),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );
```

Comment: Can you provide the current code that makes duplicate requests

Comment: Maybe you could use some variation of `distinctUntilChanged` ? Without seeing some code it's hard to tell!

Comment: [**Check this**](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching).

Comment: https://github.com/ngneat/cashew

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is you can create an object and serve the cache appropriately.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
.....
@Injectable({ providedIn: root })
export class StudentService {
  studentCache = {};

  getSudentData(id: string) {
    if (this.studentCache[id]) {
      return studentCache[id];
    } else {
      return this.http.get(`/student/${id}`).pipe(
        // assuming your requests are always successful, you can extend to handle errors
        tap(studentData => {
           // store this response in the cache as an observable
           this.studentCache[id] = of(studentData);
        }),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

There might be a better way to do it or maybe a library like `ngrx` can help in this regard.